# Linq to SQL - How to compare against a collection in the where clause?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'd like to compare against an IEnumerable collection in my where clause.  Do I need to manually loop through the collection to pull out the column I want to compare against, or is there a generic way to handle this?

I want something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Cookie> GetCookiesForUsers(IEnumerable<User> Users)
{
    var cookies = from c in db.Cookies
              join uc in db.UserCookies on c.CookieID equals uc.CookieID
              join u in db.Users on uc.UserID equals u.UserID
              where u.UserID.Equals(Users.UserID)
              select c;
    return cookies.ToList();
}
```

I'm used to using the lambda Linq to SQL syntax, but I decided to try the SQLesque syntax since I was using joins this time.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/

```
public IEnumerable<Cookie> GetCookiesForUsers(IEnumerable<User> Users)
{
    var cookies = from c in db.Cookies
              join uc in db.UserCookies on c.CookieID equals uc.CookieID
              join u in db.Users on uc.UserID equals u.UserID
              where Users.Contains(u.UserID)
              select c;
    return cookies.ToList();
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
public IEnumerable<Cookie> GetCookiesForUsers(IEnumerable<User> Users)
{
    var cookies = from c in db.Cookies
              join uc in db.UserCookies on c.CookieID equals uc.CookieID
              join u in db.Users on uc.UserID equals u.UserID
              where Users.Select(x => x.UserID).Contains(u.UserID)
              select c;
    return cookies.ToList();
}
```

Comment: The second one works for me and does indeed create an IN statement.  Thanks a bunch, and for the resource link as well!